# How to make an input box with a button that redirects to that page

Tags: html

I'm not really sure how to explain what I'm trying to do, but if you understand, that's great.

Alright, so basically I'm trying to make an input box or whatever with a button beside it saying "Answer", and whatever you write in the input box and press the Answer button, it will open a new tab and add that to the URL, (Example: "http://yourwebsite.com/Whatever-You-Wrote-In-The-Box").

If you need me to try to explain further, go ahead and ask, I can't figure out how to do this at all.

Thanks,

Comment: Does the URL have to look like that? If not, this is just basic html forms. [You can learn about them and how to create them from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form). To make it open a new tab, just set the `target` attribute of the `<form>` to `_blank` and make the `method` attribute `GET` so the answer will appear in the URL.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input id="answer" />
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('http://yourwebsite.com/' + document.getElementById('answer').value);">Answer</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a form:

```
<form action = "http://www.yourwebsite.com" method = "get">
  <input type = "text" name = "fieldname"/>
  <button type = "submit">
    submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: This answer is good if  you don't have to make it look exactly like `http://yourwebsite.com/Whatever-You-Wrote-In-The-Box`. Otherwise Quantastical has the answer that will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Ahh true, I wasn't sure if they wanted the output to be exactly like the example or not. I'll leave this answer here anyway in case someone else needs it

Comment: I think this is a better answer anyways as it doesn't have to rely on javascript and there is a possibility that the OP was using that URL as a rough example (the op just said that it has to add the answer to the URL).

Comment: Yeah I was assuming that about the example URL as well

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with HTML only. You must use something for the interaction like javacript.

So u could do this.

```
<input id="input"/>
<button id="button">button</button>

<script>
$('#button').click(function(){
    var urlPart = $('#input').val();
    var url = 'https://google.com/' + urlPart;    
    window.location.replace(url);
});
</script>
```

Check for an example
https://jsfiddle.net/joepenzo/g873knd6/10/